# Python tab autocompletion in script

Tags: python, autocomplete, python-3.6

How do I add tab completion to my Python (3) code?
Let's say I have this code:

```
test = ("January", "February", "March"...)
print(test)
answer = input("Please select one from the list above: ")
```

I want the user to type: Jan[TAB]
and for it to autocomplete to January.
Is there any simple way of doing this? Modules and scripts allowed.
Note: The list would be long, with non-dictionary words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using linux, you can use `readline`, if windows, you can use `pyreadline`, you need to install it if not have:

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    import pyreadline as readline

CMD = ["January", "February", "March"]

def completer(text, state):
    options = [cmd for cmd in CMD if cmd.startswith(text)]
    if state < len(options):
        return options[state]
    else:
        return None

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(completer)

while True:
    cmd = input("Please select one from the list above: ")
    if cmd == 'exit':
        break
    print(cmd)
```